# The trial started tomorrow

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis

Please help me and tell if the sentence in the title is grammatically correct. When is it possible to use it ?
Peace.

Comment: It would be possible to use it in some sort of sarcastic or ironic sense, but not in any serious work.

Comment: You could use it in a nonsense poem, such as *I went to the pictures tomorrow, And took a front seat at the back; I fell from the floor to the ceiling, And broke a front bone in my back*.

Comment: It's arguable whether this is ever grammatical, but I've come across statements like 'In the original programme of events, the fair started tomorrow' for 'According to the original programme of events, the fair was due to start tomorrow'.

Comment: Maybe in the context of a dream or a cognition about tomorrow's events. In your **finished** dream the trial started tomorrow. Perhaps in reality the trial is today.

Comment: Thank you for answers. It was a puzzle given by my descriptive grammar lecturer. Later he wrote: please consider the following questions: On what basis do we assume that the sentence "The trial started tomorrow" has to narrate something, i.e. tell a story? How would it be if it belonged in a completely different text genre? Such as a "past (ergo inactive) arrangement"?
Are we sure that the verb form "started" really predicates a "fact"? What if nothing at all happened?

Comment: Please rephrase the title of your posting as a question. Please state was research you've done prior to asking. Thanks.

Comment: My lecturer gave me and other students this sentence without 
question mark. I asked here for help, in the meantime he gave what I wrote above your post. Unfortunately, I'm fledgling when it comes to English grammar and I can not understand everything properly. Greetings ;]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe correct in the *Back To The Future*.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use it unless it is to illustrate a grammatical error in the use of tenses. 
You are combining past tense(started) and future tense(tomorrow). The sentence should read " The trial starts tomorrow".